# Cycle Nested Functions Technical Word

Tags: function, functional-programming, specifications, call-graph

I´m writing my thesis and I don´t know the technical word to define functions that create a cycle in a Call Graph. If the arrow is a call instruction, imagine this example: **A -> B -> C -> A**.

I´m treating them differently in my tainted analysis and I'm currently calling them "Cycle Nested Functions". Is any technical word to define them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are [mutually recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) functions.

Comment: Also: they are *re-entrant*.

Comment: Ok thanks, but to explain what I want is better to call them mutually recursive